# how to convert my code behind in visual studio 2019 from aspx.vb to aspx.cs in order to create a asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to create a .net website. I am using visual studio 2019. The code behind appears to be in aspx.vb. Kindly guide me to get it back to aspx.cs. I am a student who is trying to learn. Please help!

Comment: If your just learning, dont use a code converter, your better off treating the page's functionality as a requirement and figuring out how to do it C#. With the existing VB code to help you it should be a breeze.

Comment: you can use some vb to c# converter https://converter.telerik.com/. but like @mxmissile said, you better write it yourself if you are a student. it is far better

Answer (score 0):

I have had luck in the past with using Telerik's Code Converter.

https://converter.telerik.com